# Unable to access storage in Android Q

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-storage

Although having read and write permissions I am unable to access sdcard in Android 10. This was my approach to list all directory.

```java
        File root = new File("/mnt/sdcard/");

        File[] subFiles = root.listFiles();

        for(File file : subFiles)    {
            if(file.isDirectory())  {
                String str = text.getText().toString() + "\n";
                str+=file.getAbsolutePath();
                text.setText(str);
            }
        }
```

If I use `/mnt/` instead of `/mnt/sdcard/` I can see `sdcard` directory is listed in there but when I use `/mnt/sdcard/` , `subFiles` is `null`. I don't know if this is something regarding new android 10 version or it is a problem with emulator. I was using android studio's default emulator for debuging.

Comment: android 10 uses scoped storage, read more here
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: @PembaTamang Thanks. I read the documentation of scoped storage from your suggestion and fixed my problem.

Comment: Do NOT assume the location of the sdcard is /mnt/sdcard like that.  It can and does vary between OEMs.  This code may have other issues, but its broken due to that as well.

Comment: Is there any default location from where I can navigate to sdcard? @Gabe Sechan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is a temporary solution. From Android 11 Scoped Storage have to be used.

The problem was `requestLegacyExternalStorage` was not set to `true` in the manifest file. Because of scoped access on external storage by default it is set to `false` in Android 10 or higher. Adding this line in the `AndroidManifest.xml` solved my problem.

```java
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application 
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ........ >
    ......
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do not take that as a long term solution. This feature is expected to be removed in a next android version

Comment: You can use this attirbute but when app uninistall filename exits but data inside file unisttaled